# Update database table from Radio button. I'm using Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, database, sql-update, radio-button, codeigniter-4

I can't update my table. Anyone to help me

Code in view :

```
<form  method="post"
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('home/savecovid') ?>>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="radio" name="anotasi1" value="Positif" 
                <?php echo set_radio('anotasi','positif'); ?>/>Positif<br>
                <input type="radio" name="anotasi1" value="Negatif"
                <?php echo set_radio('anotasi','negatif'); ?>/>Negatif<br>
                <input type="radio" name="anotasi1" value="Netral"
                <?php echo set_radio('anotasi','netral'); ?>/>Netral
            </div>
                <button type="submit" name="saveCovid">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Code in my controller :

```
public function savecovid()
    {
        $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
        $anotasi1 = $this->request->getPost('anotasi1');
        $builder = $db->table('tbl_anotasi');
        $data = [
            'anotasi' => $anotasi1
        ];
        $builder->set('anotasi');
        $builder->update($data);
    }
```

I want to update my table
[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DOWm.png)

Comment: What error or problem are you getting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

use model oky   and entity

```
$model =new Mymodel();
$model->update($id,$data)
```

go this link

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html